# How to set font size for all devices using story board in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, autoresize, uifont

I am searching for any way to fix the problem of font re-sizing according to the device size by using mainstoryboard. I can do it by using the code but still searching is it possible to do so by using mainstoryboard. To better describe my problem let suppose i have a text field on iphone 4s size i am using 14 font size but when i put it on ipad the view will be too large in size so that there must me a way to increase the font size.

Comment: Have a looks at size classes.

Comment: Why iPad and iPhone share the same storybord, make different for both.

Comment: But by using re sizing concept we can sahre the same story board for both @Retro

Comment: Yes, but they are two different family have many different things so its better to have different Storybord as practice of ideal approach.

Comment: it means using size classes are waist of time? @Retro

Comment: Size class are for different iPhone screen sizes like 5, 6, 6+ as they are trying to solve another problem of autolayout.

Comment: Actually till now i create two set of xib 1 for iphone and another for ipad, i am happy with that but recently i found that there is no need to create it sepratly apple provide special feature to do so, so i decide to switch from my traditional style to new style, all UI design is compatible besides the font size.

Comment: So in your opinion having two set of xib would be a great idea?@retro

Comment: It can be easily done with the help of autolayout

Comment: Please let me know if any one has concern for the same